# How do I programmatically add a field to a Commerce Line Item?

Tags: commerce

I'm running Drupal 7 and Drupal Commerce 1.4. I need to programmatically create a simple text field on Line Item of type Product. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Same way you'd programmatically add a field to any other entity type - what have you tried so far? Could you post the code along with a description of what doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I simply got the type and the bundle all mixed up, so it didn't work for me at first.